# monkeypatch exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

running on `nodev4` -

let's say that I have 2 libraries : `foo` and `bar`

`foo` has this

```
var bar = require('./lib/bar');
exports = module.exports = function myApp(options) {
 [snip]
}
exports bar = bar;
```

and `bar` has this

```
module.exports = function doStuff(moreOptions) {
  function doMoreStuff () {
  }
}
```

my app has

```
x = requires(foo);
```

what I would like to do is get my app to monkeypatch the `doMoreStuff` function - is this possible ?

I have tried various libraries , but I suspect there's a fundamental problem with my understanding of js ;)

Comment: In your bar module, the function `doMoreStuff` is scoped to the `doStuff` function, which prevents it from being accessed outside of the `doStuff` function definition.

Comment: monkey-patch how? what new functionality you want to add? you should return `doMoreStuff` for it to be accessible.

Comment: this is a function in another library that I would rather not fork and PR just for the changes needed. I wanted to intercept the function to get some of the data that was being passed in, but not exposed.

Comment: so I guess I am faced with having to fork and modfiy - thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at what you have here. After

```
x = requires(foo);
```

you have the following essentially

```
x = function (options){ /* function work */ }
x.bar = function(moreOptions){
    function doMoreStuff(){
    }
}
```

This, while not 'illegal' it is odd. It's the equivalent of

```
a = function() { return "I'm a function"; }
a.bar = "I'm a string attached to a function";

console.log(a());   // => "I'm a function"
console.log(a.bar); // => "I'm a string attached to a function"
```

Your bar module doesn't do much. It's a function containing an inaccessible function. Lets assume you meant

```
module.exports = function(moreOptions){
    return {
        doMoreStuff: function(){
            return "Bar doing more stuff";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to new up an myApp and attach an external function you would

```
function myApp(options){

}
myApp.prototype.bar = bar();        // since you exported a function
module.exports = myApp;
```

In your main app you could now

```
x = require('foo');

var app = new foo();    // you MUST otherwise you get an empty function
app.bar.doMoreStuff();  // => "Bar doing more stuff"
```

Alternatively (and less prone to error) foo could be

```
var bar = require('bar');
module.exports = function (options) {
  // work here ...
  return {
    bar: bar(),    // again, exported as function
    appOptions: options,
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then in the main module

```
x = require('foo');
x.bar.doMoreStuff();   // => "Bar doing more stuff";
```

Hope this helps.